# Accurate area calculation for countries worldwide individually

Tags: coordinate-system, area, proj, equal-area

I have polygons of countries with its administrative divisions, I would calculate the areas of each division in a country accurately.

I got the bounding boxes for each country, then I divided its width (longitudely) by its height (latitudely).

If the

- `ratio = 1`, the country extends equally South-North as West-East
- `ratio < 1`, it extends West-East
- `ratio > 1`, it extends South-North

But I made my own criteria:

1. If the `ratio < 0.7`, I used an Albers equal-area projection `+proj=aea` with the 1st SP parallel is `1/6` degree below the northernmost latitude of the country, and the 2nd SP is `1/6` degree above the southernmost latitude.
2. If the `ratio is between 0.7 and 1.3`, I used Lambert azimuthal equal area `+proj=laea` centered at the center of the bounding box.
3. If `ratio > 1.3`, I used transverse cylindrical equal-area `+pro=tcea` with central meridian is at the center meridian of the country and `k_0=0.9996`

Do you agree that this lets me get accurate areas relatively better than a projection for the whole continent or the whole world, or is it a boring time taking method?

Comment: 1) You need to decide what precision you are interested in, to square km, square m, square cm, square mm :-), 2) it is not clear what the source projection you have identified the shape and size of the States, they are all different projections; 3) would you like to calculate the exact area of the States with regard to elevation +another accuracy in height; 4) Knowing the shape of States, I would choose one or two equal-area projection and bore their original dates, for example, the centroids of each state, and then calculated its area, in any case, continue with your experiments...

Comment: My precision would be sufficient in sq.meter, I think, I would have large difference in area for large countries (e.g. Russian Federation)  if I follow my criteria, bcz of its large administrative divisions (for example Sakha Republic is so large) but for european countries is better

Comment: In order to perform the calculation with such accuracy, you must have the original cartographic data with an accuracy of at least 1:10,000 scale on the whole Earth, a cheerful picture is obtained...